# An array of latest wp_titles

Tags: posts

I want to get the latest titles with the_title() in an array so that I can loop through them in my javascript function.

How can I create this array?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WordPress function **wp_get_recent_posts()**, with required args.

```
$output = array();

$args = array(
'numberposts' => 10,
'offset' => 0,
'category' => 0,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'include' => ,
'exclude' => ,
'meta_key' => ,
'meta_value' =>,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
foreach( $recent_posts as $post ) {
   $output[$post["ID"]]['title'] = $post["post_title"];
   $output[$post["ID"]]['title'] = get_permalink($post["ID"]);

}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse158654_recent_posts');
function wpse158654_recent_posts() {?>
  <script type="text/javavscript">
   var recent_posts = <?php json_encode( $output ); ?>;
  </script>
}
```

Or you can use the **wp_localize_script()** function to print the variable for required js.

**I haven't tested the code, be careful if you are using it on live site directly.**

Answer (score 2):

An example using [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) which is a clean solution to insert JavaScript variables in the page.

```
// Attaching to the wp_enqueue_scripts hook because of wp_localize_script()
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse158654_js_post_titles' );

function wpse158654_js_post_titles() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3, // Number of posts to pick up
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $post_titles = array();

    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $wp_query->the_post();
        $post_titles[] = get_the_title();
    }

    // Inject a JavaScript variable into the document
    // Note: you may want to change the script handle (first argument)
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'post_titles', $post_titles );
}
```

And this should be the JavaScript variable, popping up right after the inclusion of jQuery in this case (depends on the script handle used).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var post_titles = ["Title 1","Title 2","Title 3"];
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to get the an array of [posts objects](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post), by default it returns the latest posts.

You should iterate over the array and do what you need with the titles.